# How do we know Kernels are successful in making data linearly Separable?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, supervised-learning

When we have linearly inseparable datasets and we are using machine learning algorithms such as SVMs, we use kernels to *implicitly* map datapoints into a feature space that makes them linearly separable.

**But how do we know if a kernel has indeed, *implicitly*, been successful in making the datapoints linearly separable in the new feature space? What is the guarantee?**

Comment: There's a great intuitive + mathematical answer available here (see "1. Achieving perfect separation"): http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/80398/how-can-svm-find-an-infinite-feature-space-where-linear-separation-is-always-p

Comment: @stmax Let me simplify the question. Suppose we are working with a linear kernel SVM but our data is linearly inseparable. Assume all points are distinct. How will the SVM behave? Will it converge and produce a decision surface at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot guarantee this. Some data *is* not separable by any kernel because of duplicates.

By trying too hard, you will **cause overfitting**. Essentially, you force the implicit mapping to be so complex it contains a copy of your training data (which is exactly what happens if you choose a too small bandwidth with RBF).

If you want a good generalization performance, you will have to tolerate some errors, and use e.g. soft-margin and such techniques.

Perfect separation is not something to aim for. Such a guarantee is just a guarantee of being able to overfit! Use cross-validation to reduce the risk of overfitting and find the right balance between being optimal on training data and actual performance.

Comment: @Anony-Mouse **But then if there is no guarantee, does that mean that we can't use hard-margin and kernels on linearly inseparable data?** I know using soft-margin generalizes better and that in that case an imperfect separation is fine...I'm just wondering about the case when it is hard-margin.

Comment: There exists data that is *impossible* to separate. Example: (0,0,classA), (0,0,classB). No kernel *ever* can separate these classes, because the data is identical. Thus: no guarantee of making data linearly separable is possible on such data sets.

Comment: @Anony-Mouse Withstanding such examples (which is reasonable because it is a contradiction):  **But then if there is no guarantee, does that mean that we can't use hard-margin and kernels on linearly inseparable data?**

Comment: @Anony-Mouse Let me simplify the question. Suppose we are working with a linear kernel SVM but our data is linearly inseparable. Assume all points are distinct. How will the SVM behave? Will it converge and produce a decision surface at all?

Comment: Convergence and result depend on your optimization procedure, this cannot be answered for the abstract SVM *model*. If e.g. your data is (0,0,+), (0,1,-), (1,0,-), (1,1,+) and you use the linear kernel, then there exists no SVM that has 100% accuracy. But what the program does that is responsible for finding the "optimal" SVM is an entirely different question. This is a nontrivial optimization problem.